# flowing lights in structured text

Tags: plc, structured-text

I am very new to structured text, so pardon my simple question.

I am using OpenPLC to create this simple program. I have been following the example from the link below to create flowing lights simple program with structured text. In this video, they used 5LEDs and controlled it with case statements.
However, my question is, if my program needs to turn on 100 lights, how should I change the code?
Should I use for loops? How?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXnaULHpxC8&t=25s

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `for loops` etc. to make the program more "dynamic".

Unfortunately most of the PLC's don't give you dynamic access to their digital outputs. This means that at the end you will have to write code that will translate the value from array (which you will be looping through) into digital outputs.

Comment: can you give me an example of how can use for loops to make the program more "dynamic".

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that. First let me show how you can create chasing light for up to 16.

```
PROGRAM PLC_PRG
    VAR
        iNumOfLights : INT := 6;
        fbCounter : CTU := ;
        fbTicker : BLINK := (ENABLE := TRUE, TIMELOW := T#100MS, TIMEHIGH := T#1S);
        wOut: WORD;
    END_VAR

    fbTicker();
    fbCounter(CU := fbTicker.OUT, RESET := fbCounter.Q, PV := iNumOfLights);
    wOut := SHL(2#0000_0000_0000_0001, fbCounter.CV);

    A := wOut.0;
    B := wOut.1;
    C := wOut.2;
    D := wOut.3;
    E := wOut.4;
    F := wOut.5;
    G := wOut.6;

END_PROGRAM
```

Or if you know output address you can do it directly to outputs.

```
PROGRAM PLC_PRG
    VAR
        iNumOfLights : INT := 6;
        fbCounter : CTU := ;
        fbTicker : BLINK := (ENABLE := TRUE, TIMELOW := T#100MS, TIMEHIGH := T#1S);
        wOut AT %QB0.1: WORD;
    END_VAR

    fbTicker();
    fbCounter(CU := fbTicker.OUT, RESET := fbCounter.Q, PV := iNumOfLights);
    wOut := SHL(2#0000_0000_0000_0001, fbCounter.CV);
END_PROGRAM
```

You can also change type of chasing lights by something like.

```
IF fbCounter.CV = 0 THEN
    wOut := 0;
END_IF;
wOut := wOut OR SHL(2#0000_0000_0000_0001, fbCounter.CV);
```

Now what is behind this. `SHl` operator will move `1` to the left on set number. For example `SHL(2#0000_0000_0000_0001, 3)` will result in `2#0000_0000_0000_1000`. So we assign it to `wOut` and then access individual bits by `wOut.[n]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Can I ask you about the code for that `fbTicker : BLINK`  BLINK block?

Comment: You can create it yourself or use OSCAT library.